# update row using php framework silex

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, api, silex

I am making an angular application, for the backend I am creating a REST api using symphony's microframework: **silex**.

On a certain update I keep getting an internal server error. All I try to do is update the weight.

```
$app->put('/{id}/updateWeight', function ($id) use ($app) {

  $sql = "UPDATE results SET weight=20 WHERE usersId = $id";
  $test = $app['db']->executeUpdate($sql, array((int) $id));

  return $test;

});
```

Comment: Please post the server error

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use placeholders, but you're putting `$id` in the query anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding guys, I took another look at the error right before I wanted to post it and I found the problem.

I assumed the error was created inside the piece of code I posted above but actually it seemed that this route got mixed up with another one, this one:

```
$app->put('/{name}/{goalsId}', function ($name, $goalsId) use ($app) {

$sql = "UPDATE users SET goalsId=".$goalsId." WHERE username ='".$name."' ";
$users = $app['db']->executeUpdate($sql, array($goalsId, (int) $name));
//$user = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql, array((string) $username));
return $goalsId;

});
```

This obviously created the error.

changing the route from

```
$http.put("../api/web/"+user.usersId+"/updateWeight/")
```

to

```
$http.put("../api/web/updateweight/"+user.usersId)
```

did the trick.